# Craft 3 update failure

Tags: craft3, database, updates

i wanted update a new installed craft3 and got this message:
[image]

I took a look in the web.log file. The first line from today gives an error:
2018-04-25 03:39:23 [85.7.133.198][-][-][error][yii\base\InvalidConfigException] yii\base\InvalidConfigException: Unsupported DB driver value:  in /home/velolade/craft3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/config/DbConfig.php:187

What's wrong here?
Thank you in advance for help!

Answer (score 1):

The original poster solved this in a follow-up comment:

> After checking the log file - see my other question -, i activated the php functions "proc_open" and "proc_close" at my hoster's php settings and it worked. I'm not sure if i can leave these settings.

`proc_open` and `proc_close` are required if you want Craft 3 to automatically backup your database because it uses the native `mysqldump` and `pg_dump` binaries to perform the backup.

If, for whatever reason, you can't enable those methods, your options are to:

1. Set the [backupCommand](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-config-generalconfig.html#property-backupcommand) config setting to `false`. This will prevent Craft from performing database backups and you'll be responsible for manually creating them.
2. Set the [backCommand](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-config-generalconfig.html#property-backupcommand) config setting to some other script or service that can perform a backup without using those disabled methods.  Craft will respect whatever is set in this config setting.

Comment: Anyone actually do this yet (implement alternate way)? Would be amazing with a config flag to use a method not reliant on proc_open and so forth for us wrangling open_directory hosting...

Answer (score 0):

Is the DB_DRIVER line set in your .env file? You may need to run the `./craft setup` script.

Comment: Thanks! I checked my .env file: DB Driver ist set to: DB_DRIVER="mysql". I also realized that i couldn't backup my database. After checking the log file - see my other [question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/25891/craft-3-database-backup) -, i activated the php functions "proc_open" and "proc_close" at my hoster's php settings and it worked. I'm not sure if i can leave these settings.