# Craft 3 Database Backup

Tags: craft3, database, security, back-up

Why do I have to activate the PHP functions: "proc_open" and "proc_close" to backup the database?

I got the error logs:

> [error][yii\base\Exception] yii\base\Exception: Could not create backup: proc_open() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/velolade/craft3veloladen_daten/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/UtilitiesController.php:383
>
> [error][yii\base\Exception] yii\base\Exception: Could not create backup: proc_close() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/velolade/craft3veloladen_daten/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/UtilitiesController.php:383

After activating these functions in my hoster's PHP settings, it worked.
Is this a security problem for my website?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Craft uses MySQL's native [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) and PostgreSQL's [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/app-pgdump.html) binaries to create database backups.

In order for PHP to be able to execute those binaries, it needs to be able to run the `proc_open` and `proc_close` PHP commands.

I would not consider it a security issue, but if you were really concerned about it, you can [prevent Craft from making backups on update](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-config-generalconfig.html#$backupOnUpdate-detail) and/or specify your own [backup logic](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-config-generalconfig.html#$backupCommand-detail) bypassing Craft's default implementation.

Comment: How did Craft 2 do it? Craft 2 worked flawlessly with openbasedir, Craft 3 does not.

Comment: Not sure what this post has to do with openbasedir?

Comment: openbasedir disables proc_open(), no? That seems to be how shared hosting typically works in any case.

Comment: Ahh, a host that might use openbase_dir, might also happen to disable some proc_ methods, but they are technically unrelated.